# Reading from keyboard with Ruby

Tags: ruby, keyboard

I'm using Windows.

Is there a Ruby Way to make a dll call? I want to use the `GetAsyncKeyState()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't been a Windows user in a long time, but there's a `Win32API` library. Maybe this article helps:

http://www.rubytips.org/2008/05/13/accessing-windows-api-from-ruby-using-win32api-library/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [WIN32OLE](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/WIN32OLE.html) library, or the [DL](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/dl/rdoc/index.html) library. They are designed for DLL access and Windows programing in Ruby. (NOTE: Although the librarys work, dynamic C access from Ruby does not seem to be an easy task, so use them only for sparse calls to the API. A Win32 program will do better in C, C++, C#, or .NET)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give [FFI](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Why-use-FFI) a look. It provides a fairly seamless interface to native libraries.